# Unspecified number of parameters in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Arrays and a method that expects N arguments of type Array.

For example, if I have:
`let arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]];`

`arr` has 3 arrays inside, so I could do this:

```
theFunction(arr[0]);
theFunction(arr[0], arr[1]);
theFunction(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

The question is: How can I accomplish this if I don't know the number of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   theFunction(...arr)
```

Just *spread* the array into the function arguments.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the "spread" concept